# Might "Require TLS Encryption" in Exchange mail-flow rules cause compatibility issues for e-mail?

Tags: ssl, exchange, microsoft-office-365, encryption, email-bounces

[image]

Picture of how I'm forcing TLS.

This is essentially forced TLS.
Should "Require TLS Encryption" be required for microsoft exchange mailflow rules?

1. I'm worried about compatibility issues, e-mails not being sent or received if I force TLS encryption in Microsoft Exchange for e-mail.
   Worst case is someone sends an e-mail and we never receive it, they receive an e-mail bounce because it can't be TLS encrypted. I'd rather leave TLS encryption out than miss important e-mails or assume I sent my e-mail and it never goes through.
2. What's the default encryption if any if TLS isn't forced in Microsoft Exchange for Outlook?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on my knowledge, If you decide to configure TLS between your organization and a trusted partner organization, Exchange Online can use forced TLS to create trusted channels of communication. Forced TLS requires your partner organization to authenticate to Exchange Online with a security certificate in order to send mail to you. Your partner will need to manage their own certificates in order to do this. In Exchange Online, we use connectors to protect messages that you send from unauthorized access before they arrive at the recipient's email provider.For more details: [How Exchange Online uses TLS to secure email connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/exchange-online-uses-tls-to-secure-email-connections?view=o365-worldwide)

Steps for [configuring forced TLS for Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

2. By default, Exchange Online always uses opportunistic TLS. This means Exchange Online always tries to encrypt connections with the most secure version of TLS first, then works its way down the list of TLS ciphers until it finds one on which both parties can agree.

I have found an article on email encryption for your reference: [Comparing email encryption options available in Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/email-encryption?view=o365-worldwide)